# What if I like two answers with different votes equally well?

Tags: discussion, voting

Suppose I like two answers equally well. One of them has 5 upvotes, the other one only 4. Somehow I am inclined to only upvote the answer with 4 votes, so as to make them have an equal number of upvotes in total. Is that sensible or stupid?

Note that I'm not talking about answers to my own question and choosing a correct one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you like both answers, upvote both.

Right now they might be at 5 and 4 votes, but tomorrow they could be at 7 and 8 votes, respectively. In other words, some time down the line, the first answer could be missing out by not having received the upvote you wanted to give it but didn't.

Just use your votes to reflect your own opinion. Don't let others' votes confuse you.